# Records are fetched very slow when joining view inside view in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want to fetch Records from a View but there is a other view which is left joined in my query which is causing to fetch the records very slowly.

Its taking 5 minutes to fetch 13000 records.

My view is as below -

```
CREATE View [dbo].[VIEW_IQ_PURCHASE_ANALYSIS]                           
As                          
    SELECT             
    ISNULL(MstOrganization.Name,'') as [Organization Name] ,   
    ItemLedger.DateDelivered AS [Date Delivered],                                                   
    Characteristics.*            
    FROM VIEW_ITEM_STOCK_LEDGER as ItemLedger        
     LEFT JOIN **VIEW_PRODUCT_WITH_CHARACTERISTIC_COLUMN_DATA** as Characteristics on Characteristics.Code = ItemLedger.ItemCode            
     LEFT JOIN MstGroup ON MstGroup.Code = ItemLedger.GroupCode     
     LEFT JOIN MstOrganization ON MstOrganization.Code = ItemLedger.OrganizationCode    
     LEFT JOIN MstCurrency As BaseCurrency On BaseCurrency.Code = MstOrganization.CurrencyCode    
     LEFT JOIN stmVoucherType ON stmVoucherType.Code = ItemLedger.VoucherTypeCode    
     LEFT JOIN MstCurrency As DocumentCurrency ON DocumentCurrency.Code = ItemLedger.DocumentCurrencyCode    
     LEFT JOIN MstUser ON MstUser.Code = ItemLedger.UserCode                                                                                                                  
     LEFT JOIN MstBusinessPartner ON MstBusinessPartner.Code = ItemLedger.PartyCode    
     LEFT JOIN MstWalkinCustomer ON MstWalkinCustomer.Code = ItemLedger.PartyCode     
     LEFT JOIN MstAddressDetail As BusinessPartnerAddressDetail ON BusinessPartnerAddressDetail.ObjectCode = MstBusinessPartner.Code                                                                   
        AND BusinessPartnerAddressDetail.IsDefault = 1    
     LEFT JOIN MstWalkInCustomerAddressDetail As WalkInCustomerAddressDetail ON WalkInCustomerAddressDetail.ObjectCode = ItemLedger.PartyCode                                                                   
      AND WalkInCustomerAddressDetail.IsDefault = 1     
     LEFT JOIN MstAddressType As BusinessPartnerAddressType ON BusinessPartnerAddressType.Code = BusinessPartnerAddressDetail.AddressTypeCode     
     LEFT JOIN MstCity As BusinessPartnerCity ON BusinessPartnerCity.Code = BusinessPartnerAddressDetail.CityCode     
     LEFT JOIN MstCountry As BusinessPartnerCountry ON BusinessPartnerCountry.Code = BusinessPartnerAddressDetail.CountryCode     
     LEFT JOIN MstState As BusinessPartnerState ON BusinessPartnerState.Code = BusinessPartnerAddressDetail.StateCode    
     LEFT JOIN MstCurrency As BusinessPartnerCurrency ON BusinessPartnerCurrency.Code = MstBusinessPartner.CurrencyCode    
     LEFT JOIN MstUOM As DetailUOM ON DetailUOM.Code = ItemLedger.DetailUOMCode    
     LEFT JOIN stmItem ON stmItem.Code = ItemLedger.ItemCode    
     LEFT JOIN MstUOM As ItemUOM ON ItemUOM.Code = stmItem.UOMCode    
     LEFT JOIN mstProductCategory ON mstProductCategory.Code = stmItem.ProductCategoryCode    
     LEFT JOIN mstTax ON mstTax.Code = ItemLedger.TaxCode                                                                                                                  
     LEFT JOIN MstStockPoint ON MstStockPoint.Code = ItemLedger.StockPointCode                                                                  
     LEFT JOIN MstBusinessPartner As SalesmanBuyer ON SalesmanBuyer.Code = ItemLedger.SalesmanBuyerCode                                           
     LEFT JOIN MstShipper ON MstShipper.Code = ItemLedger.ShipperCode    
    WHERE (ItemLedger.vouchertypecode=204 OR (ItemLedger.VoucherTypeCode=402 and  ItemLedger.DocumentTypeCode=2))
```

There is another View in my above view called - **VIEW_PRODUCT_WITH_CHARACTERISTIC_COLUMN_DATA** which i am joining with my view.

**VIEW_PRODUCT_WITH_CHARACTERISTIC_COLUMN_DATA** is as below -

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW_PRODUCT_WITH_CHARACTERISTIC_COLUMN_DATA  
AS 
    SELECT mstProduct.Code,  
    (SELECT ISNULL((SELECT mstProductCharacteristicListDetail.ListValue      
    FROM mstProductCharacteristicListDetail WHERE 
    mstProductCharacteristicListDetail.HeaderCode = mstProductCharacteristicDetail.ProductCharacteristicCode      
    AND mstProductCharacteristicListDetail.SequenceNo = mstProductCharacteristicDetail.CharacteristicValue),'')  
    FROM mstProductCharacteristicDetail   WHERE mstProductCharacteristicDetail.ItemCode =  mstProduct.Code     
    AND mstProductCharacteristicDetail.ProductCharacteristicCode =  10011786 ) 
    As [Sub Category], 
    (SELECT ISNULL((SELECT mstProductCharacteristicListDetail.ListValue      
    FROM mstProductCharacteristicListDetail      
    WHERE mstProductCharacteristicListDetail.HeaderCode = mstProductCharacteristicDetail.ProductCharacteristicCode      
    AND mstProductCharacteristicListDetail.SequenceNo = mstProductCharacteristicDetail.CharacteristicValue),'')  
    FROM mstProductCharacteristicDetail   
    WHERE mstProductCharacteristicDetail.ItemCode =  mstProduct.Code     
    AND mstProductCharacteristicDetail.ProductCharacteristicCode =  10011787 ) As [Brand], 
    (SELECT ISNULL((SELECT mstProductCharacteristicListDetail.ListValue      
    FROM mstProductCharacteristicListDetail      
    WHERE mstProductCharacteristicListDetail.HeaderCode = mstProductCharacteristicDetail.ProductCharacteristicCode      
    AND mstProductCharacteristicListDetail.SequenceNo = mstProductCharacteristicDetail.CharacteristicValue),'')  
    FROM mstProductCharacteristicDetail   
    WHERE mstProductCharacteristicDetail.ItemCode =  mstProduct.Code     
    AND mstProductCharacteristicDetail.ProductCharacteristicCode =  10011788 ) As [Color], 
    (SELECT ISNULL((SELECT mstProductCharacteristicListDetail.ListValue      
    FROM mstProductCharacteristicListDetail      
    WHERE mstProductCharacteristicListDetail.HeaderCode = mstProductCharacteristicDetail.ProductCharacteristicCode      
    AND mstProductCharacteristicListDetail.SequenceNo = mstProductCharacteristicDetail.CharacteristicValue),'')  
    FROM mstProductCharacteristicDetail   
    WHERE mstProductCharacteristicDetail.ItemCode =  mstProduct.Code     
    AND mstProductCharacteristicDetail.ProductCharacteristicCode =  10011789 ) As [Size], 
    (SELECT ISNULL((SELECT mstProductCharacteristicListDetail.ListValue      
    FROM mstProductCharacteristicListDetail      
    WHERE mstProductCharacteristicListDetail.HeaderCode = mstProductCharacteristicDetail.ProductCharacteristicCode      
    AND mstProductCharacteristicListDetail.SequenceNo = mstProductCharacteristicDetail.CharacteristicValue),'')  
    FROM mstProductCharacteristicDetail   
    WHERE mstProductCharacteristicDetail.ItemCode =  mstProduct.Code     
    AND mstProductCharacteristicDetail.ProductCharacteristicCode =  10011790 ) As [Style], 
    (SELECT mstProductCharacteristicDetail.CharacteristicValue   
    FROM mstProductCharacteristicDetail   
    WHERE mstProductCharacteristicDetail.ItemCode =  mstProduct.Code     
    AND mstProductCharacteristicDetail.ProductCharacteristicCode =  10011791 ) As [Barcode], 
    (SELECT mstProductCharacteristicDetail.CharacteristicValue   
    FROM mstProductCharacteristicDetail   
    WHERE mstProductCharacteristicDetail.ItemCode =  mstProduct.Code     
    AND mstProductCharacteristicDetail.ProductCharacteristicCode =  10011792 ) As [Item Name Arabic]
    FROM mstProduct
```

When i execute VIEW_PRODUCT_WITH_CHARACTERISTIC_COLUMN_DATA - it fetches me record very fast (3sec) whats causing trouble is joining that view.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Those subquery in your `SELECT` are going to be terrible for performance.

Comment: yes but i need them!

Comment: when i am executing the view with subqueries which you referred @Larnu , its fetching me records in 3 seconds. So i guess problem is joining it in my first View!

Comment: You need the data, yes, but a bunch of subqueries in the `SELECT` is completely the wrong place. At a glance, I suspect that `CASE` expressions are going to help here.

Comment: Also, I **strongly** suggest using alias. That code is really bloated with those very long object names

Comment: as i said @Larnu , did all the necessary things , but as i said time taken max is while joining!

Comment: Why are you concerned about that particular view? Why not `VIEW_ITEM_STOCK_LEDGER ` or any other joined table?

Comment: because @IvanStarostin , i tried removing all joins one by one in VIEW_ITEM_STOCK_LEDGER. What took time was the join of the view.

Comment: Alright, follow Larnu tips then. And I suspect that some of joins can and must be turned into `INNER JOIN` which will affect execution plan as well.

Comment: @KrunalShah it's the entire query that gets executed and needs optimization, not just individual views. Of course, a badly written view will cause the entire query to run slowly. *Without the actual query* and the *actual execution plan* it's hard to help except to say *DON'T* use those subqueries in the `SELECT` clause. You *can* write a different query that will produce the same data faster.

Comment: @KrunalShah without any indenting, all those subqueries are unreadable. It looks like you are trying to convert an entity-attribute-value table into a proper view though. First, that's why EAV is a bad idea. Second, you can use one query with PIVOT instead to convert attribute rows to actual values

Comment: @KrunalShah finally, if you want to perform reports you need a proper reporting schema. When your queries get this complex it's a clear sign that the schema isn't suitable for that job. Instead of one big VIEW_ITEM_STOCK_LEDGER that reads live data you should have a star schema with dimensions, a fact table for the items etc. This view will be slow for even 10K rows. A star schema could handle millions of rows with minimal effort

Answer (score 3):

I'm not doing the whole query here, it's messy and awful to read (sorry, but those object names are huge, and with no aliasing it's completely bloated out).

I suspect that the following logic is going to work for your first column `[Sub Category]`, and so you'll be able to apply the same logic (which will just be more `CASE` expression, *no more subqueries*) to get the rest of the values:

```
SELECT P.Code,
       CASE PCD.ProductCharacteristicCode WHEN 10011786 THEN ISNULL(PCLD.ListValue,'') END AS [Sub Category] --This should achieve the same thing as the subquery with a subquery
       CASE PCD.ProductCharacteristicCode WHEN 10011787 THEN ISNULL(PCLD.ListValue,'') END AS [Brand]
FROM mstProduct P
     LEFT JOIN mstProductCharacteristicDetail PCD ON P.Code = PCD.ItemCode
     LEFT JOIN mstProductCharacteristicListDetail PCLD ON PCD.ProductCharacteristicCode = PCLD.HeaderCode
                                                      AND PCD.CharacteristicValue = SequenceNo;
```

*Note: Without sample data this is completely untested.*

Comment: first of all @Larnu , its not for that particular code = 10011786 , there are lots of codes, cant use case when!

Comment: @KrunalShah that's the value in your first subquery: `AND mstProductCharacteristicDetail.ProductCharacteristicCode =  10011786`. If you're saying `10011786 ` is wrong, then your `VIEW` is too.

Comment: @KrunalShah you can't avoid repeating `case` or values. That's a consequence of storing code/value pairs instead of actual fields. That's why Entity-Attribute-Value schemas are not a great idea.

Comment: @Larnu, probably OP will see the picture with any other column like `[Brand]` included and the aggregation required for this pivot-like appoach.

Comment: Good idea, I've added an extra sample column.